# integration making cases

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin x - \cos x|\,dx.$$

now we will  try to make cases  , what i did   i put  sin x - cos x = 0

this  gives tan x = 0  , but iam stuck here

I applied above logic  by taking below in consideration

$$\int_{0}^{6}|x - 3|\,dx.$$
 x -3 = 0  , x =3

$$\int_{0}^{6}|x - 3|\,dx.$$ = $$\int_{0}^{3}3-x\,dx.$$       + $$\int_{3}^{6}x - 3\,dx.$$

Comment: Hint:.....$\sin x-\cos x=0 \rightarrow \tan x-1=0 $

Comment: it shuld be  tan x = 0 , why tan x - 1

Comment: divide by $\cos x$

Comment: $\sin x -\cos x=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ may be helpful.

Comment: yup sorry sir my bad i was in a hurry

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you tried to do, but

$$x\in\left[0,\,2\pi\right]\;,\;\;\cos x-\sin x\ge0\iff x\in\left[0,\,\frac\pi4\right]\cup\left[\frac{5\pi}4,\,2\pi\right]$$

so

$$\int_0^{2\pi}|\cos x-\sin x|dx=\int_0^{\pi/4}(\cos x-\sin x)dx+\int_{5\pi/4}^{2\pi}(\cos x-\sin x)dx+$$

$$+\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}(\sin x-\cos x)dx=4\sqrt2$$

Comment: thanku sir ,   i  solved many examples on  inequalities  but not trignometric one because they are not in my exam syllabus how you solved  cos x - sin x >=0 thanks advance

Comment: Just check the graphs of $\;\cos x,\,\sin x\;$ on the interval $\;[0,2\pi]\;$ , which corresponds to the whole trigonometric circle. You must know that in order to have some hope to be able to cope with this kind of questions...

Comment: Beat me just by a minute

Comment: sir yes i know graphs , but in 3 hours exam if i try to solve by making graphs then it will waste my time , how you solved  cos x - sin x >=0 , just plz explain iam sure i will get it

Comment: @sumitgoyal This is something you should be able to do within 5 minutes... **at most** . So it fits in an exam pretty well. Any high school student must know the graphs of these two functions well enough to solve this problem. There is no "other way", as far as I can see.

Comment: can you tell me how to solve cos x - sin x >=0 , yes i will do by graph too

Comment: @sumitgoyal **The only way I can solve this is knowing how the functions behave, which involves their graphs!** I know no other way to solve it...!!

Answer (score 1):

Begin with simplifying the integrand:
$$\sin x-\cos x=\sqrt{2\rule{0pt}{2ex}}\sin\Bigl(x-\dfrac\pi4\Bigr),$$
so that by substitution ($u=x-\frac\pi4$):
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin x - \cos x|\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt{2\rule{0pt}{2ex}}\int_{-\tfrac\pi4}^{\tfrac{7\pi}4}|\sin u|\,\mathrm du=\sqrt{2\rule{0pt}{2ex}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin u|\,\mathrm du=2\sqrt{2\rule{0pt}{2ex}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin u\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: One never re-reads oneself enough… Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to separate cases. For any $C>0$ and any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|C\sin(x+\theta)\right|\,dx = 4C $$
since both $\left|\sin x\right|$ and $\left|\sin (x+\theta)\right|$ are $\pi$-periodic and their integral over a period equal $2$.
Your problem can be solved by considering $C=\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{4}$.